# Why can't I assign to unique_ptr of type uint_8[]?

Tags: c++

Consider, that I have initialised the `unique_ptr` like this:

```
unique_ptr<uint_8[]> pixels{nullptr};
```

After that, I have decided to assign a new array:

```
pixels = new uint_8[10];
```

Unfortunately, it does not allow to assign a new array of size 10*8.
I do know, that I can simply assign `std::make_unique<uint_8[]>(10)` but I just want to understand the smart pointers.

So basically, the questions are:

1. Why it does not allow the cast from `nullptr` to a new array?
2. Is `nullptr` some specific type in C++11?

Comment: *"Is nullptr some specific type in C++11?"* It's `std::nullptr_t`, but I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are doing "cast from nullptr to a new array" ?

Comment: You most likely want to you use .reset of unique_ptr. Cannot say without exact error message though, you should have included it into question

Comment: A cast implies some sort of explicit new type involved (e.g., casting `nullptr` to an `int*`). You're doing an assignment, not a cast.

Comment: @chris You are assigning but as new and std::unique_ptr are two different types, GNU compiler also tries to cast new to std::unique_ptr, therefore it throws an error (together with a missing = overload for a type std::unique_ptr (new)

Comment: I'm making a note on your misleading terminology. Your problem is that a `uint8_t*` cannot be assigned to a `unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`. There's no cast there, and mentioning a cast leads people to look away from parts of the code with no cast, which helps no one. This is where the other comment's request to show the cast came from. On the same note, `new` is not a type. It's used as part of an expression that *has* a type (`uint8_t*`).

Comment: @chris Don't you have better things to do instead of arguing in the comments section? I will edit the question but look at the answer below, it clearly does not confuse people and if you are experienced enough to answer to this question you will not be confused by the cast or paying attention to "new" being a type. Have a good day

Comment: @AlisherKassymov The Q&A on SO is obviously not for the benefit of those *experienced enough to answer to this question*, it's for others that may run into the same issue that you have and don't know the answer. So avoiding incorrect terminology is important, lest you give a beginner the impression that there is some cast involved in the assignment in your question. And most of us have better things to do than answering or commenting on questions, but we choose to do this in the hope of helping others.

Comment: @AlisherKassymov C++ is a complex language. It's not easy to get the terminology right all the time. But it does matter and it makes it easier to understand each other. To point out errors could be seen as a way to help.

Comment: @AlisherKassymov, I'll freely admit that it confused me. I was looking for a cast and it took me a good minute to realize what the question was actually about. I can't speak for others, but it's possible that M.M was also confused when making the comment. I'm simply trying to advocate good communication, having seen firsthand what happens at work when I miscommunicate something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pixels = new uint_8[10];
```

This implies that `operator=` of `std::unique_ptr` will be used. However, if you take a look at all `operator=` [overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) you will notice that there is no overload taking `T*` for `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.

The method you need is called [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) and it *resets* the old value stored in `std::unique_ptr` with the newer one:

```
pixels.reset(new uint_8[10]);
```

Comment: Ok got it, I thought so. So it only overloads if the right side is either nullptr or std::unique_ptr and std::make_unique is a type of unique_ptr?

Comment: @AlisherKassymov Not really, a unique_ptr can't be copied, only moved. The nullptr is a special case similar to calling reset. The other overload accepts an r-value reference, i.e. a moved unique_ptr.

Comment: @AlisherKassymov If you use `std::make_unique`, then the overload which accepts `unique_ptr&&` takes place. Basically, the right side should be either a `nullptr` or rvalue of type `std::unique_ptr` as `std::unique_ptr` implies exclusive ownership.

Comment: Yes, I double checked it and saw &&. I guess that is why it is unique ;) Thanks mate

Comment: @AlisherKassymov the hint in it's name :)

Comment: @AlisherKassymov The constructor for `std::unique_ptr` which takes a `T*` as its only argument is marked `explicit`, which means a pointer won't implicitly convert. Using `reset` or explicitly calling the constructor (`pixels = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(new uint8_t[8]);`) or using `std::make_unique` (`pixels = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(8);`) is the correct way to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, correct me if I am wrong, but the OP asked how to "assign". It is a very specific question, with a very specific title too. The method the OP needs is perhaps not called "reset".

```
// replaces the current payload with the new empty one
pixels.reset(new uint_8[10]);
```

It seems the above does not "assign" anything to `pixels` if I am not confused with the meaning of the term "to assign".

I boldly assume the following might be to inquirer's liking:

```
// array of uint8_t elements
using u8arr = std::uint8_t[];

// instance of the said array
// that contains 3 uint8 values
u8arr uar{0,1,2};

// declare unique_ptr to the same array type
std::unique_ptr<u8arr> smart_arr_;

// at last ! we assign to the "smart array"
assign(smart_arr_, uar);

// the proof of the pudding
::wprintf(L"\n\n%d\t%d\t%d", smart_arr_[0],smart_arr_[1],smart_arr_[2]);
```

And as if by magic, I have one implementation of "assign" ready (I have prepared earlier):

```
template<typename C, size_t N>
inline auto 
    assign
(
    std::unique_ptr<C[]> & sp_,
    const C(& arr)[N]
) noexcept
    -> std::unique_ptr<C[]> &
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<C>);
    sp_.release();
    sp_ = std::make_unique<C[]>(N + 1);
    void * rez_ = ::memcpy(sp_.get(), arr, N);
    assert(rez_);
    return sp_;
}
```

Just to make sure the good old `memcpy` will not object, I have used that `static_assert` to check on the type to be copied.